# Random 404 from localhost

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

I'm running a local server in python

```
 python -c $'import SimpleHTTPServer;\nmap = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map;\nmap[""] = "text/plain";\nfor key, value in map.items():\n\tmap[key] = value + ";charset=UTF-8";\nSimpleHTTPServer.test();' "$port"
```

**EDIT:** This is the readable version of the command string passed to `python -c`, so in pseudocode the code block above could be resumed like this: `python -c $'command' "$port"` where 
 the command part is:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
map = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map
map[""] = "text/plain"

for key, value in map.items():
    map[key] = value + ";charset=UTF-8"

SimpleHTTPServer.test()
```

and I get (seemingly) random 404 errors that prevents my js to execute correctly.

More specifically I am serving a static html page and its linked javascript files.
Chrome tells me `net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` and sometimes `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`  on this script tag on the `index.html` page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/lib/fonts.js"></script>
```

I have 3 weird behavior I don't understand:

1. if I inspect the terminal log where the python server is running I don't have any 404 error. In fact it says that the file was correctly served (200).
2. if I go to chrome's Network panel it tells me: `Failed to load response data` but if I 'open link on a new tab' I can actually see the file! 
   If I load the file `http://localhost:8000/lib/fonts.js` on another tab and I refresh many times I never get errors.
3. sometimes I don't get any 404 errors but my js does not work at all (no js errors)

So who is causing the problem? Chrome, Python or some async behavior in my js?
I suspect that the js files are not loaded in order so other js scripts could not find and use them..

**EDIT2:**
If I switch server, for example using the built-in php server:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

I won't get the errors

Comment: It may be easier for your question to be answered if you break the command line invocation out into readable python source code.

Comment: If you remove the section that adds the charset information, does it still have issues?

Comment: @col6y yes, nothing will change

Comment: I tried to replicate this, but can't seem to, even with 101MB of JavaScript files.

Comment: My best guess is that it's related to async behavior - I used Chromium and Python 2.7.8, and it worked for me. I do suspect it's related to overloading the server, but my tests didn't show that as an issue.

Comment: I made an edit, there is another hint, and I'm just more confused than before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65045/discussion-between-leonardo-and-col6y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems was caused by two different issues:

1. I've got rid of any `async` attributes on the `<script>` nodes. Especially it seems that loading jquery from google with the `async` attributes was causing most of the problems. Most probably the order of the scripts was not preserved but I've never got any error about jquery being undefined, I was getting an error on the missing script `/lib/fonts.js` weird..
2. Even tough removing `async` made things more reliable, more or less once every 10 page refresh I still got errors of the type `net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` or `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on different external resources, sometimes on a js file, sometimes on a css file. Changing the python server  with the php built-in server seems removed the remaining random errors.

So `php -S localhost:8000` is more reliable (in my case) than the python counterpart.

**NOTE:** Even tough I've solved the problem I still don't know exactly what was causing the errors so if someone else has a better answer than this he's very welcome to post. I will leave the answer unaccepted for a while.